# Parallel: Import a python file from sibling folder

Tags: python, parallel-processing, distributed-system, ray

I have a directory tree

```
working_dir\
    main.py
my_agent\
    my_worker.py
my_utility\
    my_utils.py
```

Code in each file is as follows

```
""" main.py """

import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

from my_agent.my_worker import MyWorker
import ray

ray.init()
workers = [MyWorker.remote(i) for i in range(10)]
ids = [worker.get_id.remote() for worker in workers]
# print(*ids, sep='\n')
print(*ray.get(ids), sep='\n')
```

```
""" worker.py """
from my_utility import my_utils
import ray

@ray.remote
class MyWorker():
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def get_id(self):
        return my_utils.f(self.id)
```

```
""" my_utils.py """
def f(id):
    return '{}: Everything is fine...'.format(id)
```

Here's a part of the error message I received

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/p35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 616, in fetch_and_register_actor
>       unpickled_class = pickle.loads(pickled_class)
>
> File "/Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/p35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 894, in subimport
>       **import**(name)
>
> ImportError: No module named 'my_utility'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "main.py", line 12, in 
>       print(*ray.get(ids), sep='\n')
>
> File "/Users/aptx4869/anaconda3/envs/p35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 2377, in get
>       raise value
>   ray.worker.RayTaskError: ray_worker (pid=30025, host=AiMacbook)
>
> Exception: The actor with name MyWorker failed to be imported, and so cannot execute this method

**If I remove all statements related to `ray`, the above code works fine.** Therefore, I boldly guess the reason is that `ray` runs each actor in a new process and `sys.path.append` only works in the main process. So I add the following code to `worker.py`

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

But it still does not work: the same error message shows up. Now I run out of ideas, what should I do?

Comment: I consider this `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` better than this `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')`

Comment: @spaniard Thanks:-) I guess you suggested `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))`. But this does not work either...

Comment: Have you tried to remove the line `if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:`? and simply always add to your path the parent directory?

Comment: @spaniard Yes, the same story goes on

Comment: @Darkonaut I did what you suggested, still not working. I remembered that python3 has no longer require `__init__.py`, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes since Python 3.3 it shouldn't be needed anymore, but my guess was that ray might need it somehow since it's a framework.

Comment: @Darkonaut Thanks. I've added `__init__.py` to all directory, even the root directory which contains these three folders. It still does not work.

Comment: Could be a naming conflict. You have `utils.py` and `worker.py` and I see ray has these files too. Rename your files with a prefix to avoid the clash.

Comment: @Darkonaut I did what you suggested, and prefix all relative file/class with `my`,,, still not working...

Comment: @Darkonaut Yep, I've changed all relative names... The error happens at the `print` statement. IMHO, if the error is caused by name conflict, it should not happen so late.

Comment: I cannot speak for ray but at least in standard libs `multiprocessing.Pool` it's necessary that imports for used functions are made for every distributed task _again_. I'm not familiar with ray's internals but that line `ImportError: No module named 'utils'`  makes me wonder. It looks like it's trying to import utils from `utils.py` instead of from the directory.

Comment: @Darkonaut I've updated the code, file names, and the error messages. It can be seen now that the `ImportError` refers to the folder name `my_utility` instead of the `my_utils.py` file. To my best knowledge, I think ray calls `from my_utility import my_utils` in every new actor process, and that causes this problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct about what the issue is.

In your example, you modify `sys.path` in `main.py` in order to be able to import `my_agent.my_worker` and `my_utility.my_utils`.

However, this path change is not propagated to the worker processes, so if you were to run a remote function like

```
@ray.remote
def f():
    # Print the PYTHONPATH on the worker process.
    import sys
    print(sys.path)

f.remote()
```

You would see that `sys.path` on the worker does not include the parent directory that you added.

The reason that modifying `sys.path` on the worker (e.g., in the `MyWorker` constructor) doesn't work is that the `MyWorker` class definition is pickled and shipped to the workers. Then the worker unpickles it, and the process of unpickling the class definition requires `my_utils` to be imported, and this fails because the actor constructor hasn't had a chance to run yet.

There are a couple possible solutions here.

1. Run the script with something like

   ```
   PYTHONPATH=$(dirname $(pwd)):$PYTHONPATH python main.py
   ```

   (from within `working_dir/`). That should solve the issue because in this case the worker processes are forked from the scheduler process (which is forked from the main Python interpreter when you call `ray.init()` and so the environment variable will be inherited by the workers (this doesn't happen for `sys.path` presumably because it is not an environment variable).
2. It looks like adding the line

   ```
   parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
   os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = parent_dir + ":" + os.environ.get("PYTHONPATH", "")
   ```

   in `main.py` (before the `ray.init()` call) also works for the same reason as above.
3. Consider adding a `setup.py` and installing your project as a Python package so that it's automatically on the relevant path.

Answer (score 3):

The new "Runtime Environments" feature, which didn't exist at the time of this post, should help with this issue: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/handling-dependencies.html#runtime-environments. (See the `working_dir` and `py_modules` entries.)

Comment: if you have multi dependencies, use "py_modules": ["path/project_name/module"]